# React Native flexbox styling issue with drop cap

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox

So here's a really simple drop cap I've thrown together: https://jsfiddle.net/WW3bh/31797/

```
p {
  font-family: 'arial';
  padding: 20px;
}
span {
  font-size: 60px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 45px;
  margin-top: 7px
}
```

I've been trying for a few hours to replicate this in React Native with the flexbox layout, but I'm really struggling.  Either the text doesn't start at the top of the drop cap, or it doesn't wrap around the bottom of it.  It really shouldn't be as hard as I'm making it look!

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe this is like a something so hard to do with react-native/flexbox so someone create a library for : https://github.com/novoda/spikes/tree/master/drop-cap. I didn't tried the lib.

Comment: the link is not working anymore. :(

Comment: Here is the updated link: https://github.com/novoda/drop-cap

Comment: This is a library for Android, not React Native :(